# MYSQL FROM muliple tables and multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

My SQL code:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    map_features_stations,
    map_fuels_stations
RIGHT JOIN fuelprices ON fuelprices.fuel_id = map_fuels_stations.fuel_id
RIGHT JOIN map_stations ON map_fuels_stations.station_id = map_stations.id
RIGHT JOIN map_locations ON map_stations.location_id = map_locations.id
RIGHT JOIN map_features ON map_features.id = map_features_stations.feature_id
```

I have error `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'feat.feature_id' in 'on clause'`

I have this column in my map_features_stations table.

```
SELECT * FROM map_features_stations
INNER JOIN map_features ON map_features.id = map_features_stations.feature_id
```

this works fine...

can someone help me?

---

UPDATED

---

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(map_features.id, '-', map_features.name_eng)) AS 'existingFeatures',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT map_features_stations.feature_id) AS 'allFeatures',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT map_fuels_stations.fuel_id) AS 'existingFuels',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fuelprices.fueL_id, '-', fuelprices.fuel_name)) AS 'allFeatures'

    FROM map_fuels_stations
    LEFT JOIN fuelprices ON fuelprices.fuel_id = map_fuels_stations.fuel_id
    LEFT JOIN map_stations ON map_fuels_stations.station_id = map_stations.id

    RIGHT JOIN map_locations ON map_stations.location_id = map_locations.id

    RIGHT JOIN map_features_stations ON map_features_stations.station_id = map_stations.id
    RIGHT JOIN map_features ON map_features_stations.feature_id = map_features.id

    GROUP BY map_stations.id
    HAVING map_stations.id = 1
```

I changed it. and result is:
[image]

In existing(existingGeatures and existingFuels) columns everything is good. But How Can I make, that in allFeatures and allFuels columns have all features and all fuels which is in database ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. Use explicit joins everywhere in your query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    map_features_stations
JOIN map_fuels_stations on ...
RIGHT JOIN fuelprices ON fuelprices.fuel_id = map_fuels_stations.fuel_id
RIGHT JOIN map_stations ON map_fuels_stations.station_id = map_stations.id
RIGHT JOIN map_locations ON map_stations.location_id = map_locations.id
RIGHT JOIN map_features ON map_features.id = map_features_stations.feature_id
```